# Klassifikation vs Klassifizierung

Tags: translation, word-usage

Aktuell schreibe ich über die Klassifikation von Daten, wie sie im Bereich des maschinellen Lernens getätigt wird.

Folgender Satz soll übersetzt werden:

> In classification, data is divided into groups of the same type.

Meine Versuche der Übersetzung:

> Bei der Klassifizierung werden Daten in Gruppen desselben Typs unterteilt.
> Bei der Klassifikation werden Daten in Gruppen desselben Typs unterteilt.

Welcher der beiden Varianten wäre im deutschen passender?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Welcher der beiden Varianten wäre im deutschen passender?

Das Problem ist kein sprachliches, sondern ein thematisches.
Was hier richtig ist, hängt davon ab was in dem Fachgebiet üblicherweise genutzt wird. Es ist sogar denkbar dass die Begriffe in einem Spezialgebiet unterschiedliche Bedeutungen haben.
Eine rein sprachliche Antwort, die auf Sprachgefühl oder ähnlichem aufbaut, ist dafür nicht ratsam.

Ich empfehle ein Fachforum zum Thema zu suchen und dort zu fragen, oder deutsche Texte über das Thema zu suchen und in ihnen einen Hinweis zu finden.